# Quotient of the free Poisson algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume $P$ is the free Poisson algebra on the set of generators $X = \left\lbrace x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \right\rbrace$. It is well-known that $P$ is the polynomial algebra with infinitely many generators $y_{1}, y_{2}, \ldots$ where $y_{1} = x_{1}, \ldots, y_{n} = x_{n}, y_{n+1} = [x_{1}, x_{2}], \ldots$ is a basis of the free Lie algebra on $X$.

What is the quotient of $P$ by the Poisson ideal generated by the set $\left\lbrace x_{1}, x_{2},..., x_{n} \right\rbrace$?